# Add a sonar rule to forbid use of URL GET parameter

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to add a Sonar rule to forbid use of URL GET parameters.
I mean I only want to allow POST parameters in my application forms.
Can you help me to write this rule ?

Comment: StackOverflow is not suited at all for this kind of request : you can reach SQ community on sonarqube@googlegroups.com.  Please _try_ something before asking for help, show what you have tried and moreover please precise which programing language you are talking about.

Comment: OK I will join sonarqube@googlegroups.com.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Web plugin doesn't support custom rules, you'll need to either write your own supplementary plugin (i.e. use the Web plugin plus the one providing your custom rule(s)) or submit a pull request to add your rule directly to the plugin. In either of those cases, you should probably look to the [SonarQube Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarqube) for further discussion/guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the language you want to analyse, but depending on which one you're using you can use XPath to analyse the syntax tree. If XPath isn't supported for your language you'll really have to write your own custom plugin like said in the other answer.

See here for each language support:
[SonarDocs - Writing Custom Rules](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Extending+Coding+Rules)

If you do need to write a custom plugin, I can only recommend you to take a look at the existing code, starting with [java.custom-rules](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules)

Comment: I saw this doc and I will ask specific questions on google group, thanks.